# python split strings of a text file

Tags: python, split

Sorry if my question is too basic. My results are saved as text file from FORTRAN and I have to post process it using Python. I tried to use `split` function to separate different columns, however, the space between different columns are not always equal. So is there a way to solve my problem? Below is the data:

```
 2/ 1/1961  0.0000  0.0019   ---------   0.749E+04   0.353E-02   0.374E-03
 2/ 2/1961  0.0000  0.0021   ---------   0.748E+04   0.353E-02   0.374E-03
 2/ 3/1961  0.0000  0.0000   ---------   0.743E+04   0.350E-02   0.371E-03
 2/ 4/1961  0.0000  0.0000   ---------   0.732E+04   0.345E-02   0.366E-03
 2/ 5/1961 24.0000 24.0000   0.416E-01   0.719E+04   0.339E-02   0.360E-03
 2/ 6/1961 24.0000  0.0000   0.509E-01   0.706E+04   0.333E-02   0.353E-03
```

I need to save each column as a separate variable in Python. If I use two space as separator, I will give me `2/ 5/1961 24.0000` as one variable. If I use single space, I will get , `2`, `/`,... So is there a way to process my text file? Thanks!

```
x_date=[]
fp = open("results_file.txt")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if (i >= line_start) and (i <= line_end):
        line = line.split(' ')
        x_date_temp = line[0]
        x_date.append(x_date_temp)
```

Comment: Just use `.split()` it will autodetect whitespace

Comment: @wim, I think `" 2/ 6/1961"` may represent a date, so it shouldn't be split that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is from Fortran, it's almost certainly fixed width fields, not space delimited, so it's a good idea to read it that way. It's even possible that if the second field can be "124.0000", there will be no whitespace between those two fields.

Python doesn't really have a nice builtin way of reading fixed width fields (as it does for csv). Using regular expressions is not too bad though

```
import re
x_date = []
fp = open("results_file.txt")
for i, line in enumerate(fp):
    if (i >= line_start) and (i <= line_end):
        line = re.match("(.{10})(.{8})(.{8})(.{12})(.{12})(.{12})(.{12})", line).groups()
        x_date_temp = line[0]
        x_date.append(x_date_temp)
```

You can also re to make you a dict of the fields like this

```
line_dict = re.match("(?P<date>.{10})"
                     "(?P<field1>.{8})"
                     "(?P<field2>.{8})"
                     "(?P<field3>.{12})"
                     "(?P<field4>.{12})"
                     "(?P<field5>.{12})"
                     "(?P<field6>.{12})", line).groupdict()
```

Comment: I like the re.match approach! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use replace function to get rid of '/ ' from your string and then apply split without params and this will give what you want i guess. Try this:

```
with open("results_file.txt") as f:
    x_date  = [line.replace('/ ', '/').split() for line in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
In [2]: l = " 2/ 1/1961  0.0000  0.0019   ---------   0.749E+04   0.353E-02   0.374E-03"

# this will eliminate the blank elements in the list
In [3]: [x for x in l.split() if x]
Out[3]:
['2/',
 '1/1961',
 '0.0000',
 '0.0019',
 '---------',
 '0.749E+04',
 '0.353E-02',
 '0.374E-03']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
line = line.split()
```

may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

easy

```
L = "2/ 1/1961  0.0000    0.0019    ---------   0.749E+04   0.353E-02   0.3" 
N = [x for x in L.split()]
print (N[3])
```

Output of N[3] is 0.0019 for example :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
f = open('results_file.txt', 'r')

data = [ re.split(r'\s+', line, maxsplit=7) for line in f]
for line in data:
    print line
```

## Then you will get the output like:

```
>>> 
['2/', '1/1961', '0.0000', '0.0019', '---------', '0.749E+04', '0.353E-02', '0.374E-03\n']
['2/', '2/1961', '0.0000', '0.0021', '---------', '0.748E+04', '0.353E-02', '0.374E-03\n']
['2/', '3/1961', '0.0000', '0.0000', '---------', '0.743E+04', '0.350E-02', '0.371E-03\n']
['2/', '4/1961', '0.0000', '0.0000', '---------', '0.732E+04', '0.345E-02', '0.366E-03\n']
['2/', '5/1961', '24.0000', '24.0000', '0.416E-01', '0.719E+04', '0.339E-02', '0.360E-03\n']
['2/', '6/1961', '24.0000', '0.0000', '0.509E-01', '0.706E+04', '0.333E-02', '0.353E-03']
```